# Play Framework: Changing Java language level

Tags: java, playframework

How can I change the Java language level in Play framework?

I have some code that works with 6.0, but not above. If I change the language level in IntelliJ IDEA, I can compile my code there, but Play seems to use its own compiler settings.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an example to set the source compatibility to java 1.7, you can adapt it to different versions. Add `javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.7")` to your `play.Project(...).settings` (in `project/Build.scala`) so that it looks like this:

```
val main = play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(
  javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.7")
)
```

Not sure if the play idea task automatically picks up this setting when generating idea project artifacts. Eclipse users e.g. can add the following so that the language compatibility is used for generating eclipse artifacts:

```
EclipseKeys.executionEnvironment := Some(EclipseExecutionEnvironment.JavaSE17)
```

(needs `import com.typesafe.sbteclipse.plugin.EclipsePlugin._`)

Comment: Thanks @MartinGrotzke, this looks useful. However I don't quite understand what you mean with "Add to your play.Project(...).settings". Where do I find those settings?

Comment: @MichaelJunk You find it in `project/Build.scala`. There you should have s.th. like `play.Project(appName, appVersion, appDependencies).settings(javacOptions ++= Seq("-source", "1.7"))`. I adjusted the answer...

Comment: Thanks, again. Do you by any chance know, how I can check what it is using during runtime, e.g. by issuing a System.out.println? I can compile my code fine in IDEA, but the compiler Play is using reports "Execution exception [RuntimeException: java.lang.InstantiationException]";

Comment: Clarification: I can compile **and run** my code in IDEA, but not in Play.

Comment: When starting play it prints also the java version (e.g. "play! 2.1.1 (using Java 1.7.0_17 and Scala 2.10.0)", as shown here http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/resources/manual/gettingStarted/images/playNew.png). By default play uses the java executable from the path so you could also check with `java -version` (you can also see which java process is running sbt / play via `ps axf | grep java | grep sbt`).